# Unable to read from temporary file

Tags: haskell, tmp

I'm trying to invoke an external process which writes to a temporary file which I obtain with [withSystemTempFile](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/temporary-1.3/docs/System-IO-Temp.html#v:withSystemTempFile). After the process exits, I'm able to `cat` the content of that file, but the application itself fails with `openFile: resource busy (file is locked)` error when trying to read that file with [readFile](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/strict-0.3.2/docs/System-IO-Strict.html#v:readFile). I followed suggestions in answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5053135) question and used the lazy version of `readFile`. Here's an example code:

```hs
module Main where

import Prelude hiding (readFile)
import System.Process (createProcess, shell)
import System.IO (Handle, hShow)
import System.IO.Temp (withSystemTempFile)
import System.IO.Strict (readFile)

main :: IO ()
main = withSystemTempFile "temp.txt" doSomeStuff
    where
        doSomeStuff :: FilePath -> Handle -> IO ()
        doSomeStuff tempFilePath tempFilePathHandle = do
            putStrLn tempFilePath
            createProcess $ shell $ "echo \"test\" >> " ++ tempFilePath
            getLine -- It's here just to stop program while I check that I can actually "cat" the temp file
            -- here I'm able to cat the temp file
            contents <- readFile tempFilePath -- here the command fails with /tmp/temp23900-0.txt: openFile: resource busy (file is locked)
            putStrLn contents
```

I'm still getting my head around Haskell, so I hope it's not something obvious, as I've run out of ideas. What gives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is because `withSystemTempFile` locks the file upon entering. It gives you its handle in return (called `tempFilePathHandle` in your code), so you can read the file using the handle, like this:

```
contents <- hGetContents tempFilePathHandle
```

**EDIT**

This is because GHC internally implements a [readers-writer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock) lock to track which files it has opened, and what permissions are required. A readers-writer lock allows either only one writer (exclusive access), or multiple readers (shared access).

In this case, `withSystemTempFile` gets a writer lock on the temp file, and therefore `readFile` can't get the reader lock it needs (because, again, the writer lock prevents GHC from getting any reader locks on that file).

Here is a [link](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/blob/4898df1cc25132dc9e2599d4fa4e1bbc9423cda5/rts/FileLock.c#L79) to the C code implementing the lock. As @luqui suggests in the comment below, it perhaps isn't an optimal solution, especially since GHC doesn't request any OS-level locks, so processes like `cat` can still access and modify the files. It might make more sense in a lazy context, where reading *and* writing on a file would produce hard-to-predict results.

Comment: @luqui I appreciate your edit, but I wonder why, then, the OS would allow other processes (eg. `cat`) to access the file, but not Haskell.

Comment: @luqui Looking at [the code responsible for obtaining the lock](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/blob/4898df1cc25132dc9e2599d4fa4e1bbc9423cda5/rts/FileLock.c#L79) in GHC, I can see it's implemented using a readers-writers lock, but it looks like that lock is only used internally, and it doesn't look like Haskell is requesting a lock from the OS, at least not from what I can see looking at the source code and from the output of `lslocks`.

Comment: I'm sorry, it was an "intuitive" correction because I had a hard time believing that GHC maintained an accounting of which files it had already opened  (esp because you might open two "different" files which are hard links of each other, etc).  But I appreciate you digging into the guts and defer to your more evidential reasoning.

Answer (score 4):

`withSystemTempFile` opens the temp file that it makes for you, so you don't need to open it again. `readFile` takes the file's name and not its handle, so you know it must be trying to open it itself. The equivalent of `readFile` but for a file you already have open is `hGetContents`, so to fix the problem, replace `readFile tempFilePath` with `hGetContents tempFilePathHandle` (and update your `import` accordingly).